# Custom facebook page tab issue

Tags: facebook

So, for whatever reason, some people can't see the custom facebook page tab. Not sure why, especially when I can see it just fine.

Link: http://on.fb.me/rKNxUS

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a https version of the page tab? If they're account always uses ssl and you don't you might run into issues. Other times I've seen resetting the app secret help with issues like this.

Comment: Facebook shows a confirmation dialog "would you like to temporally disable safe browsing" if https version isn't available. It never disables the entire tab.

Comment: Well I tried it and it was blank for me so just thought I'd check. I know what it should do but whether or not it was, was another matter! Is it possible you are only showing information to people who have liked your page?

Comment: I tried the resetting App Secret bit, didn't work. I think it's definitely a https issue. I don't have a SSL attached to the domain, however in page tab url areas, the links I added use http:// ...so I'm not sure why https:// comes up when people check out the page. Another question, if I did add a SSL, would the content show?

Comment: Not too sure. But facebook did state all apps should support SSL by 1st October. You can get trial certificates at some places for 30days so that might be worth investigating to see if it does fix the issue to begin with

Comment: Just added a SSL certificate and now it all works. Thanks folks!

Comment: So are you going to mark this as the answer? Just helps others see it was actually resolved if they are searching for the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It shows a standard browser error page to me. "This webpage is not available Google Chrome's connection attempt to incontrolwebsites.com was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured."

**May it be possible you didn't upload the webpage to the production server?**

If it opens correctly from your machine: check that you don't have a custom DNS setting to point to your local webserver instead of the production server.

Comment: I think it's definitely a https issue. I don't have a SSL attached to the domain, however in page tab url areas, the links I added use http:// ...so I'm not sure why https:// comes up when people check out the page. Another question, if I did add a SSL, would the content show?